# Need help calling anonymous function/plugin through chrome extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, anonymous-function

I am developing a chrome extension to automate parts of a website. I need to trigger the click event of a link. It has an event handler through an anonymous function like this...

```js
(function($, dialog) {
 function toggle(event) {
 }
 
 function addEventListeners() {
  form.on('click', '.toggle', toggle);
 }

 function init() {
 }

 $(init);
}(jQuery, window.silk.classes.dialog));
```

Traditional methods such as $('#elm').click(), trigger(), triggerHandler(), etc. do not work. I guess I need to raise the toggle() function within the anonymous plugin.

I can figure out how to trigger it through the extension, if someone can help me figure out how to trigger the handler through the console.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: If I understand you correctly in that your trying to trigger this from the console for testing purposes, then there is only one possible way. You have to have the program stopped at a break point for the console to have any knowledge of the context of functions in your program. Otherwise the console knows nothing about the javascript on your page.

Comment: I don't necessarily need this called from the console. I just need to figure out a way to invoke the link's click event handler via a chrome extension. As mentioned, since it is within an anonymous function, traditional methods don't work. Perhaps, I am not triggering the click event right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out. At the end of the day, I was trying to trigger a handler within an anonymous function. The following lines of code served to that end.

```
        var btn = document.getElementById('toggle');
        btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee, false);
            }, false);

        var event = document.createEvent('Event');
        event.initEvent('click', true, true);
        btn.dispatchEvent(event);
```

Answer (score 1):

I thought you have at least 2 anonymous functions, the one in this snippet, and also in jquery.js file
Since manifest3 anonymous functions are not allowed, so you have to modified them, just setting a name and using it

Answer (score 0):

Anything wrapped within a `function functionName(){}` block in javascript will not be invoked without an explicit call to the `functionName()`.

Typically for an annon init function I would do:

```
(function(params){
     toggle();
     addEventListeners(); //should change this it's bad to name functions after language defined ones.
     init();
})();

function toggle(params){

}
function addEventListeners(){

}
function init(){

}
```

The way you have currently written your code in the example above, the code within `addEventListener` will never run because it's never invoked (as far as I can see from what you've posted).

If you wanted to keep it the way you have it, you would have to also invoke the functions from inside your annon function because of scope:

```
(function($, dialog) {
    function toggle(event) {
    }

    function addEventListeners() {
        form.on('click', '.toggle', toggle);
    }

    function init() {
    }

     toggle();
     addEventListeners(); 
     init();
}(jQuery, window.silk.classes.dialog));
//your functions are now out of scope here, however any eventListeners you attach to the dom will stay defined until that dom element is destroyed.
```

Comment: I just posted a skeleton of the original code. The above javascript is not written by me, rather on a website for which I am developing a chrome extension. In the original the init() does call the addEventListeners(). I just need to figure out how to trigger the click event handler either through the content script or an injected JS script